# EC2 c5.xlarge ASAv instance has no public DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image: ASAv EC2]

My ASAv has 4 network interface:

- 100.0.1.10 - Outside subnet
- 100.0.2.10 - Inside subnet
- 100.0.10.50 -  Management subnet (Diagnostic)
- 100.0.10.100 - Management subnet (Management)

If I assign a public ip to the private subnet it does not happen.

If I assign it to the management subnet, everything is created correctly.

Internet Gateway is routed to the private and management subnet.

Answer (score 0):

This might explain the behaviour of DNS Name assignment to your instance:

From [DNS attributes for your VPC - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support):

> The following VPC attributes determine the DNS support provided for your VPC. If both attributes are enabled, an instance launched into the VPC receives a public DNS hostname if it is assigned a public IPv4 address or an Elastic IP address at creation. If you enable both attributes for a VPC that didn't previously have them both enabled, instances that were already launched into that VPC receive public DNS hostnames if they have a public IPv4 address or an Elastic IP address.
>
> - `enableDnsHostnames`: Determines whether the VPC supports assigning public DNS hostnames to instances with public IP addresses. The default for this attribute is `false` unless the VPC is a default VPC.
> - `enableDnsSupport`: Determines whether the VPC supports DNS resolution through the Amazon provided DNS server. If this attribute is `true`, queries to the Amazon provided DNS server succeed. For more information, see Amazon DNS server. The default for this attribute is `true`.